# CSS - relative positing element to right and moving next element to its place

Tags: css, css-position

I think this is very basic CSS question .

But here is the fiddle and below is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/G6pqC/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#topDiv {
    width:280px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:red;
}

.element{
    position:relative;
    right :100px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="topDiv">
    <input  type="button" value="button1" />
    <input  type="button" value="button2" />
    <input  type="button" value="button3" />
    <input  class='element' type="button" value="button4" />
    <input  type="button" value="button5" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Can I know how I can move button5 to the first line and as a last element ? I moved button 4 to right and now I have place in the first line , But still button5 is going to the next line . Any one please ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: They're all on one line for me with button 4 on top of button 2. Are you just trying to get all 5 on the same line?

Comment: Thanks for your response Rick and Yes Button5 also on the same as end element , by not increasing the  DIV width .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you increase the width of #topDiv? Like this:

```
#topDiv {
    width:320px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G6pqC/1/

Comment: No , sorry the width is fixed

Comment: I came up into this situation where we merged three elements and the free space is not being taken by next elements

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to #topDiv like so: http://jsfiddle.net/G6pqC/4/. Crazy hack.

Comment: Maybe I am seeing something different than everyone else but even the first fiddle had all the buttons on the same line for me in Chrome...

Comment: See it now in Firefox, it's just the font size forcing the buttons to be too big. Set them in a fixed pixel size at about 11px and it fixes the problem

Comment: Yes white-space: nowrap; helped me . Here is what I did with your solution http://jsfiddle.net/G6pqC/8/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - Check this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6pqC/6/)

```
#topDiv {
    width:280px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:red;
}

input[type="button"]{ margin: 0 0 0 -4px; }
input[type="button"]:first-child { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak , This helps me for this exact scenario . But conceptually looks like there is no way I can move button5 to button4 position just by only playing with button5 . I mean when I moved button4 to right I have space of button4, so there should be some way to occupy that space without modifying other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, loaded it in Firefox and now I'm seeing it. Just adjust the font size on the buttons.

```
.element{
font-size:11px;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
#topDiv {
width:280px;
height:500px;
background-color:red;
position:relative;
}

.moved{position:absolute;right:150px;}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="topDiv">
<input  class='element'  type="button" value="button1" />
<input  class='element'  type="button" value="button2" />
<input  class='element'  type="button" value="button3" />
<input  class='element moved' type="button" value="button4" />
<input  class='element'  type="button" value="button5" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Rick , This helps me for this exact scenario . But conceptually looks like there is no way I can move button5 to button4 position just by only playing with button5 . I mean when I moved button4 to right I have space of button4, so there should be some way to occupy that space without modifying other elements.

Comment: see edit, floating them will make them take up the space, you have to absolutely position the moved button though or it won't work.

Comment: Thank You Rick . true we have to use absolute position . The trick I followed is jsfiddle.net/G6pqC/8  . Thanks again for giving me the quick solution

Answer (score 0):

```
#topDiv {
width:280px;
height:500px;
background-color:red;
}

.element{
float: right;

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="topDiv">
<input class='element' type="button" value="button1" />
<input  class='element' type="button" value="button2" />
<input  class='element' type="button" value="button3" />
<input  class='element' type="button" value="button4" />
<input  class='element'type="button" value="button5" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

not sure if this is what ur after but there.
​

Comment: Thanks Lonergan .. But this is not the one .Please look at Chris solution